# Почему программа игнорирует блок кода?

Tags: java

Программа должна заменить все числа в поступающей строке на 0, но преобразований не происходит. Помогите найти ошибку.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(replace(getString()));

}

public static String getString() {
    String s = scanner.nextLine();

    return s;
}

public static String replace(String s) {

    if (s.contains("1")) {
        s.replace("1", "0");
    }

    if (s.contains("2")) {
        s.replace("2", "0");
    }
    if (s.contains("3")) {
        s.replace("3", "0");
    }
    if (s.contains("4")) {
        s.replace("4", "0");
    }
    if (s.contains("5")) {
        s.replace("5", "0");
    }
    if (s.contains("6")) {
        s.replace("6", "0");
    }
    if (s.contains("7")) {
        s.replace("7", "0");
    }
    if (s.contains("8")) {
        s.replace("8", "0");
    }
    if (s.contains("9")) {
        s.replace("9", "0");
    }
    return s;

}
```

}

Comment: А вы пробовали пользоваться отладчиком?

Comment: Да, там вроде бы все как и должно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [`String.pelpace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) не меняет строку, на которой он вызван, он возвращает новую строку. Соответственно Ваш код должен выглядеть как то так

```
...
s = s.replace("9", "0");
...
```

Так же посмотрите на метод [`String.replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), он принимает на вход регулярное выражение, которым можно найти все вхождения за раз:

```
s = s.replaceAll("[0-9]", "0");
```

https://ideone.com/dkRGkO